# doing a calculation on a time formatted cell in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have three cells IN , OUT& OverTime all formatted as [h]:mm,
The OT cell has this forumla,

```
=ROUND(IF(((D10-C10)+(D11-C11))*24>7,((D10-C10)+(D11-C11))*24-7,0)/24*96,0)/96
```

that calculates OT to the 1/4 hr

```
8 C D E F 
9   IN      OUT      O/T  C/T
10 7:30 AM 12:15 PM 1:45
11 1:00 PM 5:00 PM
```

When the employee clockes out for the day, I would like the following
code to run;

```
Dim CT As Date
Title = "Add to CompTime from OverTime"
If Range("E10") > 0 Then
CT = InputBox("Add Hours to CompTime?", Title)
If CT > 0 Then Range("F10").Value = ("E10" - CT)
Else: Range("F10").Value = " "
End If
End Sub
```

Everthing seems to work except;
If CT > 0 Then Range("F10").Value = ("E10" - CT)
I know it is a formatting issue but I am unable resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to do the explicit referencing to ranges whether they are on sheets or modules. Use proper properties of the objects - in your case you have a range `E10` which is **not qualified**. Assuming you are working in Sheet 1:

```
Option Explicit
'--Beginning of your Subroutine...
Dim Title as String '-- assuming
Dim CT As Date '-- are you sure you want to have a date here?

Title = "Add to CompTime from OverTime"

  If Sheets(1).Range("E10").Value > 0 Then '-- assuming it's a valid date here...
    CT = InputBox("Add Hours to CompTime?", Title)
    '-- assume your CT = 2:45 and OT = 75:30
    '-- use the following as mentioned in my comment
    If CT > 0 Then 
       Application.Text( Sheets(1).Range("F10").Value ,"[h]:mm")  = 
       Application.Text(Sheets(1).Range("E10").Value, "[h]:mm") - Application.Text(CT, "[h]:mm") 
    Else
       Sheets(1).Range("F10").Value = " "
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

PS: If you are trying to calculate hours, you may have just use VBA to do the entire calculations.. =)

Comment: Sorry I didn't post all the code for this worksheet. All assumtions where correct. Dim as Date is the problem. Yes I need to calaulate hours, I have a weekly total for OT in [h]:mm format, would like a formula to subtract x hours from OT and return the same format to a new cell, and reduce the OT total by same x hours.

Comment: Oops I have missed out your comment. I suggest you format your CT and OT in VBA using `Application.Text(cellvalue,"[h]:mm")` then substract.

Comment: I added your suggestions, there's still a formatting issue with CT. If the Value of E10 (Total OT)  = 17:15 and CT = 7:15, i get a Type mismatch error on both lines "Application.text..." code. If I hover over - Application.Text(CT, "[h]:mm") The value of CT = 7:15:00 AM. It like the [h]:mm format has not been applied.

Comment: Let me give this a try now I am front of a machine :) sorry forgot about it totally. But can I please clarify one thing, I am going to test out with `Total OT = 17.15 and CT = 7.15`.

Comment: No, 17:15 not 17.15 and 7:15 not 7.15, Results should move 7:15 hrs to CT and leave 10:00 hrs in OT, Remember the cells are formatted as [h]:mm

Comment: What I was telling you do not have to format the cells as `[h]:mm` in sheet level. You can just do all in VBA. You will only see 10 hours in the sheet.

Comment: Can I send you a copy of the Worksheet? It might be easier to see what I'm working with.

Comment: I guess it's best at this juncture..yeah carry on :)